# Prove that $\dfrac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3} \geq xyz + \dfrac{3}{4}|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|$

Tags: inequality

> For nonnegative real numbers $x,y,$ and $z$ prove that $$\dfrac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3} \geq xyz + \dfrac{3}{4}|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|.$$

The absolute value sign seems to make this difficult. Should I prove this in two cases? One for $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x) \geq 0$ and one for $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x) < 0$?

Comment: You could assume $x\leq y\leq z$ then $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ is non-negative. Re-arranging the letters only changes the sign of $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$, so the absolute value is symmetric, so you can re-arrange the values to ensure that $x\leq y\leq z$.

Answer (score 3):

First from AM-GM inequality,
$$
\left(|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|\right)^{1/3}
\leq \frac{|x-y|+|y-z|+|z-x|}{3}\leq \frac{2}{3}(x+y+z)
$$
and
\begin{align}
\left(|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|\right)^{2/3}
&=\left(|(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2|\right)^{1/3}\cr
&\leq \frac{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2}{3}\cr
&=\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz).
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3}-xyz&=\frac{1}{3}(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)\cr
&\geq \frac{3}{4}|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|.
\end{align}

Comment: Did you assume $x≤y≤z$?

Comment: no need, he's working with the absolute value.

Comment: How is $\left(|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|\right)^{1/3}
\leq \frac{|x-y|+|y-z|+|z-x|}{3}\leq \frac{2}{3}(x+y+z)
$ true?

Comment: $|x-y| \leq x+y$, etc

Comment: I mean $\left(|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|\right)^{1/3}
\leq \frac{|x-y|+|y-z|+|z-x|}{3}$.

Comment: it is Cauchy inequality

Comment: @SiXUlm It's actually AM-GM.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove a stronger inequality:
$$\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3} \geq xyz + |(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|$$

Using this equality:
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz = \frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)[(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2)+(z-x)^2]$$
we have:
$$(x+y+z)[(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2)+(z-x)^2] \geq 6|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|$$

Assume $x \leq y \leq z$. Let: $y-x = a, z-y = b, z-x = c$, then $a+b=c$ and $a,b,c \geq 0$

The inequality becomes:
$$(x+y+z)(a^2+b^2+c^2) \geq 6abc$$

This is true because:
$$x+y+z \geq z-x = c \geq 0$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2 = a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2 \geq 6ab \geq 0$$